# How to get a User object from a message in group at Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Recently I was working on a simple Telegram bot written in python (with the [`python-telegram-bot` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-telegram-bot)). In this bot I can get the last message object using following command :

```
bot.getUpdates()[-1].message
```

and according the [Telegram Doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#message) a message object is contains some attributes such as `message_id,from,date,chat` ,... which the `from` attribute returns a User object which is the sender of a message. But since `from` is a [python keyword](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) (used at import time) thus we can not use it which raise a SyntaxError.

As an alternative way we can use `chat` attribute which returns a User object in personal chats and a `GroupChat` object in groups that it doesn't contains and information about the user.Also I couldn't find any direct way to report this bug.

So the question is that is there any way to do this job? or any alternative solution maybe?

Comment: Have you tried using `getattr()`? It would let you avoid the reserved keyword. But I'm still not quite sure, did you develop the JSON to Python object code yourself?

Comment: @Anonymous No I didn't let me try that, and No It's just a simple bot without any kind of DB.

Comment: I mean, the only API they provide is an HTTP one, and I don't think there's an official python wrapper for it. If you developed the code that converts JSON to Python objects, you could just change the `from` property to `from_user` or whatever name when parsing the data. No need to stick with their convention if it doesn't work in Python. But I have a bad feeling I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: @Anonymous As I thought it raised `AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'from'`.

Comment: I don't dealing with any JSON file I just want to do what I explained in question.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in the question. Since you're using a library and not the raw API, look at the library documentation (or source) instead. [As expected, the library author renamed `from` attribute to `from_user`](https://github.com/leandrotoledo/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/message.py#L49). So just use that.

Comment: @Anonymous Yeah, thank you so much. As I'm not familiar with Telegram world I missed this simple thing. Can you pls make your comment an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it was clarified that you're using the [python-telegram-bot](/questions/tagged/python-telegram-bot) library, the solution is simple. The author of the library [renamed](https://github.com/leandrotoledo/python-telegram-bot/blob/master/telegram/message.py#L49) the Python-incompatible `from` attribute to `from_user`. So just do:

```
user = bot.getUpdates()[-1].from_user
```