# Keyword as an attribute when using Telegram API

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

In Telegram, when the user presses a button, the bot receives this information in JSON:

```
'update':
{
    'callback_query':
    {
        'from':
        {
            'id':420220883
        }
    }
}
```

There are more information in this JSON object, but I'm only interested in the `id`  part.

Now when I want to access it like `update.callback_query.from.id`, it obviously gives an `SyntaxError` error, since `from` is a Python keyword.

So my quetion is; **How can I go about using this information?**

Note that I have tried using it like a dictionary `update['callback_query']['from']['id']`, but it gives an odd-looking error.

[image]

Comment: What you have posted is not valid JSON (both in terms of not being a valid data structure and not actually being JSON but something like a python object) so it's impossible to say.

Comment: Do not catch the exception, let it raise then post the stack trace. and which telegram library are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose my question is duplicate!

The problem has been fixed by the author of the [library](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot). I should've simply changed `from` to `from_user`!

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31930309/6282576).

Answer (score 0):

The data structure you have posted is not a valid JSON nor a valid dict. After converting it to a valid dict you can easily get the 'id'

```
data = {'update':
    {
        'callback_query':
            {
                'from':
                    {
                        'id': 420220883
                    }
            }
    }}

print(data['update']['callback_query']['from']['id'])
```

Output

```
420220883
```

Comment: Ok, but you've made massive assumptions here on how that snippet fits into the actual response

Comment: As I (and others said), the data structure you have posted is not a JSON nor a dict and I dont think this is the input you get from Telegram.

Comment: You know that I'm not the OP, right? My comment is not about whether or not this actually works, but rather that you've shot for an answer that you're now telling me (thinking that I'm the OP) that you can't possibly know works or not. You've only reinforced my initial statement that you've just made assumptions.

Comment: roganjosh - there is no way this data structure is sent by Telegram. It is broken. Dont you think it is a valid assumption?

Comment: I don't know whether it's a valid assumption or not. We're both agreeing that an assumption has been made, but I'm on the side of the fence that it's not worth proffering an answer in this case until the input is clarified.

Comment: As it transpires, the issue was nothing to do with these assumptions. I know you can't vote to close yet, but I'd just pass such questions tbh rather than take time fleshing things out on an assumption.